# Voting and flagging comments gets enabled when loading additional comments in duplicate question

Tags: bug, comments, review, hidden-features

I´m not sure if it is already reported. But when i review the following post https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2764929 and take a look at the duplicate, voting on question, answers and comments is disabled.

But the accepted answer of the duplicate question has the Link "show 2 more comments" and when I click it, the additional comments are loaded and then I can vote and flag the comments of the accepted answer.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

Comment: please don't fix that bug!

Comment: @JanDvorak i´m not sure if its a bug or a hidden feature

Comment: It appears to be a known back door allowing to flag comments from within the review queue.